# Trying to add songs to Playlist using Django rest framework

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an application where user can create playlist and add songs to it.
Here is my models.py file

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Song(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my views.py file

```
class PlaylistView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Playlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer


class SongView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer


class CreatePlaylistView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreatePlaylistSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.get("name")
            description = serializer.data.get("description")
            playlist = Playlist(name=name, description=description)
            playlist.save()
            return Response(
                PlaylistSerializer(playlist).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )


class AddToPlaylist(APIView):
    serializer_class = SongSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.get("name")
            artist = serializer.data.get("artist")
            album = serializer.data.get("album")
            playlist = serializer.data.get("playlist")
            song = Song(name=name, artist=artist, album=album, playlist=playlist)
            song.save()
            return Response(SongSerializer(song).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

How my 'AddToPlaylist' returns me an error. I want 'Song' model to take the playlist name as foreign-key and add the song to playlist song_set.

I also wanna know how i can go about showing the Songs in a playlist in class PlaylistView.

Comment: i think the simple is that you can create multiple songs as you want, and there's multiple song in single playlist got it.? so when you create a playlist object this object accept multiple object of song Model that you want to add. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are used multiple type of class based view for creating api ??

Here I tried to create API with `APIView` for creating and display data like this... try this below code your side

### models.py

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Song(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

### serializers.py

```
class PlayListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = "__all__"
        

class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = "__all__"
```

### views.py

```
class PlayListAPI(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            obj = Playlist.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = PlayListSerializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        obj = Playlist.objects.all()
        serializer = PlayListSerializer(obj, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PlayListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg': 'Data Created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    

class SongAPI(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            obj = Song.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = SongSerializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        obj = Song.objects.all()
        serializer = SongSerializer(obj, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SongSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg': 'Data Created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 
    path('playlist/', PlayListAPI.as_view(),name='playlist'),
    path('playlist/<int:pk>', PlayListAPI.as_view(),name='playlist'),
    path('song/', SongAPI.as_view(),name='song'),
    path('song/<int:pk>/', SongAPI.as_view(),name='song'),
    
]
```

### POSTMAN Responses

#### POST (Adding Data)

[image]

#### GET (Display Data)

[image]